# App Passwords and BitBucket / TortoiseGit / Pageant

Tags: bitbucket, tortoisegit, pageant

I had an email Atlassian today saying I must start to use [App Password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/?utm_source=alert-email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bbc-login-deprecation_EML-12079&jobid=105398046&subid=1543643420) for linking with BitBucket.

I use:

- TortoiseGit
- Pageant

Up until now I have always input a passphrase each morning I do my first commit and there after I get no prompts.

---

I have followed the instructions to create an App Password but I do not know how to change TortoiseGit / Pageant to use this new App Password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use an AppPassword when you're not using an SSH key for authentication.

IIRC the AppPassword can just be entered as a password when you use an HTTPS-based remote.

Comment: Here is an update. With Tortoise Git I had always been using the SSH key for authentification. But as mentioned, I received an email from BitBucket saying that I can no longer use my account password and must use an AppPassword. So using SSH was not enough. At the moment I am using SourceTree. I changed all of my Git URL paths to the HTTPS version and used the AppPassword and it worked. In TortoiseGit I have changes it (atleast in one project) to use the Windows Credentials. But I have not fully tested.

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/